# prime number detector not working in the large numbers.. if i put 15 or 21 or 99... it says its a prime number

Tags: python

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter the number: ")
    new_number = int(number)-1

    while int(new_number)>1:
        detector = int(number)%int(new_number)
        new_number-=1
    if detector==0:
        print("its not a prime number")
    else:print("its a prime number")
```

Comment: I'm thinking .. What is a prime number! ????

Comment: Can you explain how you are expecting this code to work? Where are you testing factors?

Comment: try putting the `if detector==0` block one indent level deeper; and also, add `break` to the if block.. (keep the else block out)

Comment: As written, your code boils down to just checking whether the number is divisible by 2. You're overwriting `detector` on ever iteration of the loop, so only the last iteration (when `new_number` is 2) counts.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the logic used here (even if it worked) is massively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to do a quick test and then break out of the "while" loop.

Following, is a revision to your code you can try out.

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter the number: ")
    new_number = int(number)-1

while int(new_number)>1:
    detector = int(number)%int(new_number)
    if detector == 0:   # New test.  No need to go any further.
        break
    new_number-=1

if detector==0:
    print("its not a prime number")
else:print("its a prime number")
```

I believe that should perform as you want.

Regards.